# Github API : What permission should a Github App get when create an issue

Tags: github-api

## Question

How can my [Github App](https://github.com/settings/apps) get an access token that have the permission to create an issue?

## What i tried

I enabled all the permissions in the `Settings-> Developer settings -> GitHub Apps -> Permissions and webhook` page, follow the  [instructions](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) to get access token, then make a request referring the [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue)，but get the response below:

`{
    "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue"
}`

but everything work out fine when I use personal access token to make this request.

## Details

### Create a [Github App](https://github.com/settings/apps)

I enabled all the permissions

[image]

Subscribe all the events

[image]

### Get access token

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=Iv1.abfa65bfc68dc75a

[image]

[image]

https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
[image]

### Request [Create an issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue)

[image]

when I replace access_token I got from previous steps with my [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens), everything work out fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you double check that you have installed the GitHub App on your ChenViViPage/test repository? You can click the "Install App" button in the GitHub App settings page.

Answer (score 4):

Great, detailed write up of the issue you're encountering!

> follow the [instructions](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) to get access token

I think this may be the cause of the issues you are running into. You've created a **GitHub App**, but you are looking at the instructions for authorizing **OAuth Apps**.

The docs for "Authenticating with GitHub Apps" are probably what you are looking for: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/